# ASP.NET - Hangfire not reading cron expression

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm working with Hangfire in ASP.NET Core and trying to run Recurring Job every 10 mins:

```
public class TaskReminderCronService: IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    ....

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SomeMethod(), "*/10 * * * *");
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    ....
}
```

But it always throws following exception:

```
CRON expression is invalid. Please see the inner exception for details. (Parameter 'cronExpression')
```

Even if I try following expression, the exception remains the same:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => SomeMethod(), "10 * * * *");
```

Can I not use cron expression? The documentation shows it can:

https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html

Comment: it should working fine. which version of hangfire you are using ?

Comment: I did some tests with your code and she doesn't seem to have any issues, it works fine. you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)？

Comment: I removed hangfire and re-added to the project, it started working. Same version 1.7.28 installed again. Still trying to figure out, why  it was not working before.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code itself, maybe you configured some properties in the first test that caused the conflict.@Ashutosh

Comment: Yes seems to be, thanks @Chen